# tmux - exit `ctrl + b` and stay observing the session

Tags: tmux

In tmux if I press `ctrl + b` tmux expects that I am going to type something next

how do I go back if I decide that I did not want to press `ctrl + b`

Also if I go forward and tell it to do something how do I go back **to observing only** before I even pressed `ctrl + b`

I have no config I just can't find (or maybe see) the default action.
**I would like to just stick to the default way it is set to by the developer *if possible***

Thank you

Comment: Pressing escape seems to do the trick for me.

Comment: @Evert that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Press 'q'. This also works to exit out of a command in general. For example, to scroll in tmux with arrow keys, you might press 'Ctrl + B + ['. But you will get stuck in the scroll mode. To return back, simply press 'q'.